# Any way to get list of functions defined in zsh (like alias command for aliases)

Tags: zsh

I can type

```
alias
```

and get a list of defined aliases in zsh

How can I get a list of function names defined in zsh?

When I type "functions", my shell window hangs after displaying lots of functions, always ending at

```
__rvm_checksum_none () {
    [[ -z "${_checksum_md5:-}" && -z "${_checksum_sha512:-}" ]]
}
__rvm_checksum_read () {
```

What's super annoying is that this won't quit with ctrl-c (using item2 AND terminal).

iterm2:
[image]

Picture of terminal having the same issue:
[image]

Comment: Usually the listing _is_  done with the `functions` builtin. Do you get an output if you undefine the problematic(?) function first: `unfunction __rvm_checksum_read`?

Comment: What if I want to get the functions list (not full declarations)? If I unfunction that method, another __rvm_curl also has issues.

Comment: See my answer. But the behavior you describe sounds strange... so just out of interest: Does the full listing work with another terminal emulator? Can you use the problematic functions successful?

Comment: terminal has the same issue as item 2. The answer below is AWESOME. While I'd like to know why the terminal hangs just using the 'functions' command (even when piped to less), does it matter? Any reason this will cause issues?

Comment: I supposed there are some really strange character sequences in these functions which mess up the terminal. To narrow this down you could redirect the output to a file `functions > /tmp/foo`. If it's a zsh problem this should've issue, too. When it's a terminal problem it shouldn't. If your problem may interfere with everyday's usage -- I could not say, sorry.

Comment: functions > /tmp/foo also hangs, with the last bit being written as "__rvm_checksum_read () {". I'm guessing that method must have some characters that zsh doesn't like.

Comment: Just some last clues, which come to my mind: (1) Do you use a recent version of zsh? (2) Can you use e.g. the `__rvm_checksum_read` function or does this hang the shell, too? (3) Can you use `which __rvm_checksum_read` to display the function successful?

Comment: 3) which __rvm_checksum_read  hangs as well. Contents are:

Comment: __rvm_checksum_read () {
 __rvm_checksum_none || return 0
 typeset _type _value _name
 typeset -a _list
 list=()
 for _name in "$@"
 do
  list+=("$_name")
  if [[ "$_name" =~ "?" ]]
  then
   repeat st
   do
    if
    then
     for _name in "${list[@]}"
     do
      _checksum_md5="$(      "$rvm_scripts_path/db" "$rvm_path/config/md5"    "$_name" | head -n 1 )"
      [[ -n "${_checksum_md5:-}" ]] || _checksum_md5="$(    "$rvm_scripts_path/db" "$rvm_user_path/md5"      "$_name" | head -n 1 )"

Comment: _checksum_sha512="$(   "$rvm_scripts_path/db" "$rvm_path/config/sha512" "$_name" | head -n 1 )"
      [[ -n "${_checksum_sha512:-}" ]] || _checksum_sha512="$( "$rvm_scripts_path/db" "$rvm_user_path/sha512"   "$_name" | head -n 1 )"
      __rvm_checksum_none || return 0
     done
     return 1
    fi
   done
  fi
 done

}

Comment: 1) most current zsh, 2) function __rvm_checksum_read runs, and returns error code 1

Comment: I'm sorry, a cannot see a problem in these functions...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With cheating by looking at the `_functions` completion function, I'm able to answer your question:

The functions are stored in an associative array `functions`, so to get only the function names (`k` flag for *keys*) in alphabetical order (`o` flag for *ordering*) you can use

```
print -l ${(ok)functions}
```

Comment: Can you suggest a way to filter out the ones with a leading underscore?

Comment: @JS. Like so: `print -l ${(ok)functions[(I)_*]}`, see Section `ARRAY PARAMETERS / Subscript Flags` in `man zshparam`.

Comment: @JS, to exclude the leading underscore functions, it's `print -l ${(ok)functions[(I)[^_]*]}`   (surprisingly non-trivial enough for me that it seems worth sharing)

Comment: @Chris: Good point. I've interpreted "filter out" as "only", but maybe it was meant as "omit"...

Comment: @Chris Perfect!  Thank you for sharing.  Into an alias it goes!

Comment: So apparently `bck-i-search` is not a function, or a key binding. My search to find out what it actually is in the context of other things goes on.